# How to send map(key-value pair) as request parameter in a GET call

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, model-view-controller

Is it possible to send map as parameter in a GET call.? i searched and i could find for list and set collection. But did not find anything for map collection.

I tried the following,
My controller method looks like this.

```
@GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<?> mapTest(@RequestParam Map<String,String> params) {

        LOG.info("inside test with map  "+  params );

        return new ResponseEntity<String>("MAP", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

And i sent the following request from postman

```
http://localhost:8080/test?params={a:abc,b:bcd}
```

Everything works without errors and exceptions. But the map which i received looks like `key=params , value={a:abc,b:bcd}`

I expected the received map to be like `key1="a" value1=abc ,key2="b" value2="bcd"`

Comment: Have you tried changing the method parameter to `Map<String,Map<String,String>>`?

Comment: Not helping @MonkeySupersonic

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is documented in the [Spring MVC guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestparam):

> When an `@RequestParam` annotation is declared as `Map<String, String>` or `MultiValueMap<String, String>` argument, the map is populated with all request parameters.

This means that the response you currently get is the expected result. The `Map` contains a list of all parameters, and in your case, you only have a single parameter called `param`.

If you need a custom parameter mapping, you'll have to implement it by yourself. Since you're not using JSON either, you probably have to manually parse the parameter.

However, if your goal is to have a dynamic map of parameters, you can still use the `Map<String, String>`, but you'll have to change your request into:

```
http://localhost:8080/test?a=abc&b=bcd
```

Comment: OK it worked. But then i wanted to take an integer value along with that. say i want to send Map<String,String> and an Integer. So now its taking that integer as well in the map. Ex. `a=ab&b=bc&integerVal=10`  it takes all 3 in map. i want `a=ab` , `b=bc` and `integer value=10` separately.

Comment: There's nobody stopping you from adding another `@RequestParam` for the integer separately. But the `Map<String, String>` **always** contains **all** parameters. If you specifically don't want the `integerValue` to be in there as well, you'll have to remove it by yourself. Considering that it's a `Map`, that's easily done, using `params.remove("integerValue")`. However, if you're looking for a dynamic list of integer parameters as well, then you'll have to parse those numbers by yourself.