# Map as parameter in RestAPI Post request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, postman

I have created an API with a `Map<String, Integer>` parameter, like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleContactsFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                                       @RequestParam("name") String name,
                                                       @RequestParam("campaignAppItemId") Long campaignAppItemId,
                                                       @RequestParam("fileColumnHeaders") Map<String,Integer> fileColumnHeaders) throws Exception {
    if (file == null)
        return new ResponseEntity<>("No file uploaded", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    contactService.handleContactsFile(file, name, campaignAppItemId,fileColumnHeaders);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("File uploaded successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I am trying to call this via Postman:
[image]

I passed the `fileColumnHeaders` inside Body->Form Data as in the screenshot.

Then I got a message like this in Postman:

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map': no matching editors or conversion strategy found.

Anybody know why this message came ?
How can we pass a map as a parameter in Rest API request?
How can we pass a map through Postman?

Comment: What did you post? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send map as request parameter in a GET call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48823378/how-to-send-map-as-request-parameter-in-a-get-call)

Comment: I have attached the postman screenshot. Please check it

Comment: ngueno But this is a POST call

Comment: @anaskodur and how is this different from GET when it comes to `@RequestParam`? Dare looking?

Comment: and why is the File send as `@RequestParam`? That doesn't look right...

Comment: @Pijotrek Actually this is a post request. File can be sent as RequestParam. Except the map parameter all are working.

Comment: The fact that something "is working" doesn't mean it should be done this way. You can also implement login endpoint and use GET with credentials as `@RequestParam`s without `SSL`. It will be working aswell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam` for Maps and other non trivial data types and objects - this way spring will map the JSON representing your map parameter to a domain object, which is then serializable and can be converted to a java object.

Comment: Can we use RequestBody and RequestParam together in a request ? If so how can we pass those through postman ?

Comment: Judging by your screenshot, you are already passing your map in the request body.

Comment: But when i gave RequestBody for the map i got a message like this in postman    'Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------818989541995583398579446;charset=UTF-8' not supported'

Comment: @Anas, in postman you can pass requestParam under Params tab in postman. RequestBody can be passed by Body tab.

Answer (score 2):

... Or simply create a converter:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StringToMapConverter implements Converter<String, Map<String, Object>> {

  private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @Override
  public Map<String, Object> convert(String source) {
    try {
      return objectMapper.readValue(source, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {
      });
    } catch (final IOException e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you create DTO object to get all data from your request.

```
public class FormDataDTO {

    private MultipartFile file;

    private String name;

    private Long campaignAppItemId;

    private Map<String,Integer> fileColumnHeaders;

    // getters, setters
}
```

Secondly, you can map FormDataDTO from your request without any annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleContactsFileUpload(FormDataDTO formDataDTO){
    // your logic code here
}
```

Finally, form-data in your request will be:
[image]

Comment: does that work with ajax or fetch or something form js ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "upload/{fileColumnHeaders}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleContactsFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                                       @RequestParam("name") String name,
                                                       @RequestParam("campaignAppItemId") Long campaignAppItemId,
                                                       @MatrixVariable Map<String,Integer> fileColumnHeaders) throws Exception {
    if (file == null)
        return new ResponseEntity<>("No file uploaded", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    contactService.handleContactsFile(file, name, campaignAppItemId,fileColumnHeaders);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("File uploaded successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Put all other parameters into the body, but add the fileColumnHeaders to the URL like this:

`/upload/firstName=1;lastName=2;address=3;phone=4`

You will also need this extra configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
        urlPathHelper.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
        configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
    }
}
```