# Send a map as request param to a GET request in Spring Boot app

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, model-view-controller

Basically I need to accept a map along with other request parameters in a GET request.

Controller:

```
@GetMapping
public Page<Users> search(@Valid final UsersParams params) {
    return userService.search(params);
}
```

My params object looks like this:

```
public class UserParams {
    private String age;
    private String gender;
    private MultiValuedMap<String, String> names;
}
```

So, if I pass a request with these param values:

```
users?age=20&gender=Male&names={"john,doe","Harry,Potter","James,Bond"}
```

Is this even possible to pass a map in a request and make it work in a GET REST call?

With whatever minute knowledge I have, the only other option I could think of is, instead of the map use a list with comma-separated values and do some deserialization hack.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48823378/how-to-send-map-as-request-parameter-in-a-get-call

Comment: @Aakash, the only difference between my thread and his thread is he needs "all params" bound to a map, while I need a field mapped to a map, while other fields should still work.

Comment: Your `names` query parameter doesn't match the shape of your `names` property; the parameter is something that looks like invalid JSON, and it's a series of single strings, neither `MultiValued` nor a `Map`.

Comment: @AMagic There is a Spring MVC guide link provided in the accepted answer, that tells that all parameters will be added in the Map. To answer your question, it is doable, but with a caveat well explained in that answer.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I have a very rough example, do you want to suggest the correct way of passing a map in a URL, please?

Comment: "Passing a map in a URL" doesn't make much sense on its own. You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: I need to map this `names={"john,doe","Harry,Potter","James,Bond"}` into `Map<String,String> names;`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The best way you can try is make this request a post request.
Then you can use as,

Request Object

```
{
    "age" : 20,
    "gender" : "Male",
    "names" : {
        "john" : "doe"
    }
}
```

DTO

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
class UserParams {
    String age;
    String gender;
    Map<String, String> names;
}
```

```
@PostMapping("/test2")
    public void search2(@RequestBody UserParams params) {
        log.info("This is the object we got", params);
    }
```

If you want it to be GET than you can use like this,

```
/test?age=20&gender=Male&john=doe&Harry=Potter
```

```
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public void search(UserParams params, @RequestParam Map<String, String> names) {
        log.info("This is the object we got", params);
    }
```

where you will get the age and gender inside UserParams and all the pair inside names Map, You need to ignore first two entries inside names requestparam as age and gender will also come inside this.

**You can keep only Map rather than Userparam object**
[image: This is result I am getting]

Answer (score 0):

Put
`server.tomcat.relaxed-query-chars=[,]` in `application.properties` file

Then you can use a url like the one below to send params in the map

`users?age=20&gender=Male&names[john]=doe&names[Harry]=Potter&names[James]=Bond`