# Make object containing map property to querystring for Java @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, query-string

This is my class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Example {
    private boolean taxFree;
    private String email;
    private Map<Enum,String> additionalConstraints;
}
```

This is my endpoint:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/search", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public TransformedExample<Example> getPurchases(ExampleSearchQueryModel searchModel,
                                                  BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors() || searchModel == null) {
        LOGGER.error(result.getAllErrors().toString());
        return null;
    }

    return exampleService.findByExampleSearchModel(searchModel);
}
```

If i have a class and endpoint like this how would my querystring have to look like so that spring can populate the map field "additionalConstraints" ?

additionalConstraints.EMAIL=test
or
additionConstraints[EMAIL]=test

always result in the map being mapped to null or a size(0) map. How do i do this correctly?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using a `@GetMapping` I'd suggest to use `@PostMapping` so Spring can map the object directly from the body of the request.

Follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59420933/19979867)

Comment: He wants to map parameters not a body nor would that change anything (unless you would be sending JSON/XML/...).